# Running external program from command line

Tags: interoperability, external-calls

This command works on Windows:

```
 ReadList["!" <> "echo hello", String]
```

Assuming the "!" suggests Windows command shell (verified as `$SystemShell`),

However, I tried the above code in `msys.bat` which is a Unix-type shell on Windows, and it  did not work. How can I do the above operation if it is not a Windows command shell?

Do I need to replace "!"  or change `$SystemShell` somewhere?

I have tried `RunProcess` (or `ReadList`) as:

```
 path = "C:\\MinGW\\msys\\1.0\\msys.bat";   

 RunProcess[path, "StandardOutput", "echo Hello world
            exit
           "]
```

This opens `msys.bat` in a new window, and Mathematica keeps running.

Comment: Perhaps http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html can be useful.

Comment: @ilian  I tried RunProcess[], did nt work, edited question.

Comment: I know that `RunProcess` only runs executables, not batch files (which must be interpreted by the windows shell).  `ReadList` may have the same problem.

Comment: Maybe the process executed could be `cmd /c msys.bat` or similar?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MinGW, the parent project of MSYS, but my understanding is that msys.bat is only a wrapper for starting a bash shell, but it's not a command interpreter itself, so you can't really pass it shell commands to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to bypass `msys.bat` (which I think is primarily concerned with setting up the interactive console) and start the shell executable directly:

```
In[1]:= shell = "C:\\MinGW\\msys\\1.0\\bin\\bash.exe";
        RunProcess[shell, "StandardOutput", "echo $BASH_VERSION\nexit\n"]

Out[2]= "3.1.23(1)-release"
```